# How to merge the unallocated space with a drive in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I allocated 30 GB to my C drive in windows 7 at the time of installation which now I feel to be insufficient. I've 15 GB of unallocated space which now I want to merge with my C drive but I don't know know how to do that. Someone please suggest me how to carry it on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk Management

Comment: @Nitish http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2iJD0DYOmA

Comment: its not that simple....please post a screenshot of your partition layout as seen in Disk Management.. I need to know WHERE this unpartitioned space is and how is your current partition layout...

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Start Menu (or press <kbd>Win+R</kbd>), enter `diskmgmt.msc`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Right-click on `C:` and select *Extend Volume*.
3. Use the wizard to add the free space to the volume.

Comment: As C: is the system drive this will probably not work. Microsoft states that "Only the extension of data volumes is supported. System or boot volumes may be blocked from being extended...".

Comment: Then the next easiest method would be to boot a different OS like Bart's PE or Knoppix or dual-boot XP or something and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Windows 7 installation DVD to boot and select "Repair Your Computer at the Install screen". Afterwards open the "Command prompt".

There you can extend the partition using the command line tool diskpart.exe.

For the details on the required diskpart commands see the article "[How to extend a data volume...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590/en-us)".